# Checking Date Conflicts Across Two Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet that is used to make a schedule. The employees name is in Column A, and the Day of the week/Date runs across columns B-H, see the image below;
[image]

I then have another sheet (in the same document) that has employees listed across the top columns A-H, and under each employee each row would represent a day off. See the image below;

[image]

So here is what I tried so far to conditional format the cells using a forumla;

`=COUNTIFS(INDEX('Sheet 2'!$A:$H, 0, MATCH($A4, 'Sheet 2'!$2:$2, 0)), B$3)>0`

However doing this, I get a message from excel.. 'Cannot reference another workbook for conditional formatting' I have tried creating a named range on the second sheet and referencing that but still no luck. This seems like it should be a fairly easy fix but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. I'm on the latest version of office 365.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to use INDIRECT for that, but that formula, because it's [volatile](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/) so it may really overcharge your sheet combined with conditional formatting. **Edit**: Did you try creating a named range but making sure the scope of that named range is the workbook? You can chek this on name manager,

Comment: Btw the formula is working on my end. Not sure why you are getting that error, if you are in the same workbook. `=COUNTIFS(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$H,0,MATCH($A4,Sheet2!$2:$2,0)),B$3)>0`

Comment: Ugh, it seems my single quotes on 'Sheet2' were giving it a hardtime, once i removed those i didn't get the error, however for some reason i'm not seeing the formatting get applied, is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Nevermind, got it fixed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue, it seems my single quotes were giving excel a headache, once i removed those, it worked as it should.